# Avoiding deadlock in parallel-processing when operation may spawn additional tasks to run in parallel on the same thread-pool

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, deadlock

I am writing some computational code in Java and I need to restrict the entire computation to run on a specific number of threads (depending on how many cores are available and how many I am allowed to keep occupied.) A lot of the computations involve tasks that are suitable for parallel processing. So let's say I have the following setup for one such complex computation.

```java
class ComplexOpA implements Function<double[], double[]> {

    @Inject ExecutorService threadPool;

    /** 
     * Factory returns a Function<Double,Double> to call on each element 
     * of an input array 
     */
    @Inject ElementOperationFactory opFactory;

    double[] apply(double[] input) {

        int[] indices = int[input.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
            indices[i] = i;

        // Same operations need to be done on each element of `input`
        double[] output = new double[input.length];
        threadPool.invokeAll(createCallables(indices, i -> {
            double iInput = input[i];
            double iOutput = opFactory.createOperation().calculate(iInput);
            output[i] = iOutput;
        })
    }

    List<Callable<Void>> createCallables(
        int[] indices, 
        Consumer<Integer> elementOperation){
        // Create list of Callable<Void> that can be passed to 
        // the executor service.
    }
}
```

Assuming that `Function` provided by the `ElementOperationFactory` is not attempting multi-threaded execution, this will run fine without any problems. **However**, if that element-function itself was written in a way that it too uses the same thread-pool to run a computation involving parallel processing, we could have a deadlock situation. For example,

```java
class ElementOpA implements Function<Double, Double> {
    @Inject ExecutorService threadPool;
    public double apply(double input) {
        /* 
         * Assume there is a further complex operation here that the programmer
         * attempted to speed-up using multi-threading.
         */
        threadPool.invokeAll(...);
    }
}
```

In this case, we run into the problem that the fixed number of threads in the thread-pool may all be blocking on individual element-operations to complete, but no futher threads are available for the sub-tasks involved in the element-operation to execute causing them to block indefinitely.

**Could anyone suggest an approach to avoid this potential block?**

A few qualifications:

- There is no way to know how long any of the operations being carried out can take in these computations. Therefore using a timeout is not feasible.
- There is no way to tell at which level of nested operation, the programmer may be attempting to use the thread-pool for parallel processing. The computations being performed are complex with several possible implementations for the same operation depending on the specific usage.
- There is a single common thread-pool that is always accessible and available to any operation attempting to use it for parallel processing.

Comment: "fixed number of threads in the thread-pool may all be blocking"
blocking is bad, but I cannot see blocking in your code. 

Generally, to avoid blocking in thread pools, asynchronous communications are used, e.g. CompletableFuture methods.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov Let's say the pool has max 3 threads and they are processing the first three elements of `input`. All three threads are blocked on `ElementOpA.apply` that has queued additional tasks for parallel processing on the `threadPool` but those tasks don't get to run because the three threads are already running. So `ElementOpA.apply` potentially never finishes, which in turn forces the three threads to wait indefinitely. No?

Comment: use thread pool with unlimited queue size.  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads) should work.